# inner join on multiple tables, count & distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables and I am trying to join those tables with inner join. however when I use `count(distinct column_id)` it mysql through error which is

SQL syntax :  check

> for the right syntax to use near '(DISTINCT `as_ticket`.`vehicle_id`) FROM `as_vehicle` INNER JOIN `as_ticket`

My Query

```
SELECT 
            `as_vehicle`.`make`, `as_vehicle`.`model`, `as_odometer`.`value`
COUNT       (DISTINCT `as_ticket`.`vehicle_id`)
FROM        `as_vehicle`
INNER JOIN  `as_ticket`
ON          `as_vehicle`.`vehicle_id`  = `as_ticket`.`vehicle_id`
INNER JOIN  `as_odometer`
ON          `as_odometer`.`vehicle_id` = `as_vehicle`.`vehicle_id`
WHERE       `as_ticket`.`vehicle_id`   = 7
ORDER BY    `as_odometer`.`value`
DESC


Tbl as_vehicle
+------------+-------------+---------+
| vehicle_id |make         | model   | 
+------------+-------------+---------|
|          1 | HYUNDAI     | SOLARIS | 
|          2 | A638EA15    | ACCENT  | 
+-------------+------------+---------+

Tbl as_odometer;
+------------+-------+
| vehicle_id | value |
+------------+-------+
|          1 | 10500 |
|          5 | 20000 |
|          1 | 20000 |
+------------+-------+

Tbl service
+-----------+------------+
| ticket_id | vehicle_id |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          1 |
|         2 |          1 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  forgot a comma before `count`.

```
SELECT `as_vehicle`.`make`, `as_vehicle`.`model`, `as_odometer`.`value`,
        count(DISTINCT `as_ticket`.`vehicle_id`) //            here ---^
```

Comment: Ohh, i have tried that to...now it through this error

Comment: syntax to use near 'DISTINCT `as_ticket`.`vehicle_id`) FROM `as_vehicle` INNER JOIN `as_ticket

Comment: You have some invisible characters around `count`. Delete that part and write it up again on your keyboard. After that it worked for me.

Comment: How did you figured this out... LOOOOOOOL, i am going made...:) any how thanks ........

Comment: The syntax was correct and I wondered why I get an error. So I wrote it again and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not have a space after the `count()` and you have a missing comma (as already noted).  More importantly, you don't have a `group by`, so your query will return one row.

And, because of the `where` clause, the value will always be "1".  You have restricted the query to just one vehicle id.

I suspect the query you want is more like:

```
SELECT `as_vehicle`.`make`, `as_vehicle`.`model`, `as_odometer`.`value`
       COUNT(*)
FROM `as_vehicle` INNER JOIN 
     `as_ticket`
     ON `as_vehicle`.`vehicle_id`  = `as_ticket`.`vehicle_id` INNER JOIN
     `as_odometer`
     ON `as_odometer`.`vehicle_id` = `as_vehicle`.`vehicle_id`
WHERE `as_ticket`.`vehicle_id` = 7
GROUP BY `as_vehicle`.`make`, `as_vehicle`.`model`, `as_odometer`.`value`
ORDER BY `as_odometer`.`value` DESC;
```

Also, you should learn to use table aliases and all those backquotes don't help the query.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, it solved out. by juergen. Really appreciated your concernsز